# Fuzzer peach, why element "Choice" doesn't work?

Tags: fuzzer, peach

Below is my fuzz peach file. As you can see,  there is a element "Choice" in this xml file.
What I want is in result file "poc.txt", there will be randomly generate string "222" or "555", but after peach running 2 hours, there is no poc.txt contain string "222" or "555".
Peach only generate string "111" many times.
Is there anyone can tell me what's problem with my peach xml file?
why does peach always select first block?
Thanks!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Peach xmlns="http://peachfuzzer.com/2012/Peach"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://peachfuzzer.com/2012/Peach ../peach.xsd">

    <DataModel name="Customized">
        <Choice name="fjsiod">
          <Block name="Type1">
            <String value="111" mutable="false"/>
          </Block>
      
          <Block name="Type2">
            <String value="222" />
          </Block>
      
          <Block name="Type3">
            <String value="555"  />
          </Block>
          </Choice>
    </DataModel>   

    <StateModel name="State" initialState="State1">
        <State name="State1">
          <Action type="output">
            <DataModel ref="Customized"/>
          </Action>         
        </State>
    </StateModel>

    <Agent name = "LocalAgent">
        <Monitor class = "WindowsDebugger">
          <Param name = "CommandLine" value = "c:\tmp\tt1.exe h:\poc.txt"/>
          <Param name="WinDbgPath" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64" />
        </Monitor>
        <Monitor class = "PageHeap">
          <Param name="Executable" value="tt1.exe"/>
          <Param name="WinDbgPath" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64" />
        </Monitor>
    </Agent>
  
    <Test name = "Default" >
        <Agent ref = "LocalAgent" />
        <StateModel ref = "State" />
        <Publisher class="File">
            <Param name="FileName" value="h:\poc.txt" />
        </Publisher>
    <Logger class="Filesystem">
      <Param name="Path" value="Logs" />
    </Logger>
    </Test>
    </Peach>
```

Peach should generate string "222" or "555" as well.